# Unsure with writing random numbers into arrays c#

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm new to c# and don't understand 100% how to store values into arrays. My code needs to randomly generate rainfall values with a maximum number of 28mm. It has 25% chance to occur on any given day. I'm currently getting an error 'Cannot implicity convert type 'int' to 'int[]'. I intend for the numbers to be inserted into each day of each month. Any help at all would be appreciated.

```
class Program {        
    enum Months {January = 1, February, March, April, May, June, July, 
                 August, September, October, November, December}        
    static int[] daysInMonth = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
    const int MONTHS_IN_YEAR = 12;

    static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
       int[][] rainfall = new int[MONTHS_IN_YEAR] [];
       Welcome();
       ExitProgram();
    }//end Main
    static void Welcome() {
        Console.WriteLine("\n\n\t Welcome to Yearly Rainfall Report \n\n");
    }//end Welcome
    static void ExitProgram() {
        Console.Write("\n\nPress any key to exit.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }//end ExitProgram
    static void GetRainfall(int[] daysInMonth, string[] Months, int[][] rainfall)
    {
        Random chanceOfRain = new Random(3);
        Random rainfallAmount = new Random(28);
        int j;
        for (int i = 0; i < daysInMonth.Length; i++)
        {
            j = chanceOfRain.Next(3);
            if (j == 0)
            {
                rainfall[i] = rainfallAmount.Next(28);
            }
        }
    }//end ChanceOfRain
```

Comment: Where do you get the error?

Comment: Last line rainfall[i] = rainfallAmount.Next(28);

Comment: `rainfall[i][j] = rainfallAmount.Next(28);`

Comment: thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined `rainfall` as a two dimensional array so `rainfall[i]` is an array of `int[]`. You are trying to assign this array with an `int`

```
  rainfall[i] = rainfallAmount.Next(28);
```

it should be something like:

```
 rainfall[i][j] = rainfallAmount.Next(28);
```

for eaxmple.

Dont forget to initialize each row of the array before using it:

```
rainfall[i][j] = new int[5]; // if you want 5 elements
```

I think you need this:

```
static void GetRainfall(int[] daysInMonth, string[] Months, int[][] rainfall)
{
    Random chanceOfRain = new Random(3);
    Random rainfallAmount = new Random(28);
    int j;
    for(int m = 0; m < MONTHS_IN_YEAR; m++)
    { 
       rainfall[m] = new int[daysInMonth.Length];
       for (int i = 0; i < daysInMonth.Length; i++)
       {
           j = chanceOfRain.Next(100);
           if (j < 25)//25% chance
           {
               rainfall[m][i] = rainfallAmount.Next(28);
           }
       }
    }
}//end ChanceOfRain
```

The code iterates over months and initializes the array of that month with length of days on that month. Then it iterates over days and generates the values.